# CNF vs Horn Satisfiability

Tags: satisfiability, cnf, sat-solvers, horn

I know that it's easier to prove if a horn-formula is satisfiable. My Question is: Why is it easier with a horn formula rather than a normal CNF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presence or absence of [Horn satisfiability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn-satisfiability) can be shown in linear time. [Here](http://sites.cs.queensu.ca/courses/cisc204/Record/Week09/Horn%20Clauses%20and%20Satisfiability_review.pdf) is a good introduction with some examples. The solution can be found by [unit propagation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_propagation) without backtracking.

Pseudocode from a *UC Berkeley* [lecture note](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~satishr/cs270.06/lecture1.pdf):

[image]

Satisfiability for general CNF expressions is a classic [NP-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete) problem. No polynomial time algorithms are known for CNF satisfiability (except if *P=NP*).